# Why is geom_raster being smoothed out in a knitr doc?

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, geom-raster

I am plotting a matrix with geom_raster in ggplot.  If I look at the plot myself in RStudio, it is unsmoothed:

[image]

When I compile the knitr doc into a PDF, it gets smoothed somehow:

[image]

Any idea what's happening?

(Ignore the aspect ratio, I'd expect that.)

The R code is basically this (variable names changed):

```
ggplot(subset(data, x != y), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill=the_fill), interpolate=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~a_facet)
```

Comment: it's likely the pdf viewer trying to interpolate. Try turning off the 'smoothing text and line art' or similar setting.

Comment: I agree but .. where would I look for such a setting?

Comment: depends on your pdf viewer and operating system. With Preview on a Mac, it's under Preferences, PDF, "smooth text and line art"

Comment: You are a crazy genius! That worked! If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Ah, kind of sucks that then the text looks pixelated, but at least I know what is happening.

Comment: as a workaround for this pdf viewer shortcoming, `geom_tile` usually doesn't have this issue